# Importing Flash object dynamically into Flex 'layers'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a Flex Project that loads SWF files dynamically and places them into layers via `MovieClipSWFLoaders`. This works perfectly and objects are layered correctly.  However, when I load a SWF that has its own `addChild` event, it places the child within its own object as the SWF cannot reference an object it does not know exists.

I need to either move the object after creation or get Flash to recognize the `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` syntax. What would be the best way to handle this?

Should I not have any coding within the SWF file besides the animation stop/play/etc?

I am currently using the `stage.addChild` but I would like the option to have it go behind certain layers.
For a basic example I have
In the Flex Application
    `<s:MovieClipSWFLoader id="bgContainer" width="100%" height="100%"></s:MovieClipSWFLoader>`
  `<s:MovieClipSWFLoader id="obContainer" width="100%" height="100%"></s:MovieClipSWFLoader>`
  `<s:MovieClipSWFLoader id="fgContainer" width="100%" height="100%"></s:MovieClipSWFLoader>`
`bgContainer.addChild(TheBackground);`
`fgContainer.addchild(ForegroundItem);`
`loadedSWF.addObject();` --I want this object to end up in the obContainer (in front of background, but behind foreground

Now in the Flash SWF there is
`var objectInLibrary:objectClass = new objectClass();`
`function addObject (){
   stage.addChild(objectInLibrary);
 }`

The object is loaded and the function works perfectly (besides being in front of the foreground), but whenever I try to `addChild()` into `parent`, `this`, `root`, or reference `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` it throws a `ReferenceError: Error #1069`

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but `FlexGlobal` should actually be `FlexGlobals`.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add the `objectInLibrary`?

Comment: I use `FlexGlobals` all the time, I just typed it in wrong here.   I want the `objectInLibrary` in the SWF to be added to the `obContainer` when the `addObject();` function is called.  I do not want the SWF to be a part of the main application because it is not always used (and there are hundreds of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I can change the `depth` of the object before it is called and the `depth` of the `MovieClipSWFLoader`.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is a little deeper than a typical Flash SWF not knowing about  `FlexGlobals`. There are a number of workarounds there, including using `getDefinitionByName()`:

```
// In your SWF code
var globals:Object = getDefinitionByName("mx.core.FlexGlobals");
trace(globals.topLevelApplication)
```

However, you will have more problems. First, Flex components (including the top level application) do not allow just any regular display object (ie anything made in Flash) to be added to them, they usually only allow other Flex classes like `UIComponent` or `IVisualElement`.

Now, you can use [`UIMovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/flash/UIMovieClip.html) in your Flash project to allow you to create classes that are Flex display compatible.

Or, you could just add your display to the `stage`. The stage is outside of Flex, so gets around Flex control over the display. Remember that the stage is only accessible to display objects added to the display list. Adding things to the stage will put it above your entire Flex application (which itself is essentially a child of the stage), so this might not do what you want.

You could also walk up the SWF parent containers, using `root` and `parent`. Even Flex components extend `DisplayObjectContainer` so you don't have to code against Flex classes from your SWF code.

Having said all that, IMO the best way to do this is to use events. In your SWF you can dispatch a custom event that you handle in your Flex app by putting the now ready SWF display objects into the Flex component structure where and how Flex needs it to be.

Hope that helps. If you post some code and I can give you more suggestions.